# Is it possible to store secp256k1 keys inside android keystore?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have a question about storing key pairs inside Android KeyStore. For my specific use case I need to use a less common EC curve (secp256k1). The KeyPair was generated using *Spongy Castle* package and need to store them inside the KeyStore. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#SupportedKeyStoreKeys) I understand that this curve is not supported, but is there any other way to store these keys in a really secure manner.

Android API level: 29

Comment: did you have any luck finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Android Keystore does not support secp256k1.

To be 100 % sure I tried to generate such keys and this is the thrown error:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported EC curve name: secp256k1. Supported: [p-224, p-256, p-384, p-521, prime256v1, secp224r1, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1]
```